# how to add different cell editors for one column in JTable?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable with two columns and both are JComboBox,  for this purpose I implemented my own Model and overrode methods.  One of the method which I overrode is:

```
public Class getColumnClass(int index) {
  return JComboBox.class;
}
```

Also created my own ComboBoxEditor and ComboBoxRender classes,  and set cellEditor and cellRenderer:

```
column.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxEditor());
column.setCellRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer());
```

Now I want to make changes, so that for column one  some cells are JComboBox and some cells are standard textual data.

How can I achieve this ?

Any helpful suggestions would be welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement your own `javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer`, where
return different renderers at `getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)`  according to your business logic. The same for `TableCellEditor` Interface.

Comment: I think the important point is that the "default" renderers use inappropriate inheritance.

Comment: Yes, no sense in inheritance. Should be used pure composition of two renderers and return appropriate one whet it is needed.

Answer (score 9):

I usually override the table.getCellEditor(...) method to return the appropriate editor.

Maybe something like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JFrame
{
    ArrayList editors = new ArrayList(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        // Create the editors to be used for each row

        String[] items1 = { "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox( items1 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce1 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
        editors.add( dce1 );

        String[] items2 = { "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox( items2 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce2 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox2 );
        editors.add( dce2 );

        String[] items3 = { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        JComboBox comboBox3 = new JComboBox( items3 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce3 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox3 );
        editors.add( dce3 );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                    return (TableCellEditor)editors.get(row);
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };
        System.out.println(table.getCellEditor());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableComboBoxByRow frame = new TableComboBoxByRow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is very helpful camickr xD

Comment: this worked exceedingly well, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `instanceof`. Usage:

```
Object o = new String("Test");
if (o instanceof String)
{
   String s = (String) o;
   // Do something with the string
}
```

So, make the data-matrix for your JTable like this `Object[][] data = new Object[...][...]`.
Ent then can you use `instanceof` in your `DefaultTableCellRenderer` to check if the Object is a `String` or a `JComboBox`. Depending on that result, render like a `String` or a `JComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you use your own table model it would be more convenient to override
 `setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)` method and try to convert input data in it.

I'm about to use this solution in my code. Does anyone see a problem with this approach?